# Computer Theory: CFG and Regular Languages

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language

I am in the process of learning computer theory from a book by Daniel I.A. Cohen. My first problem is that I don't fully understand the words being generated by a regular expression.

Let's take this for example: `(aaa+b)*`

My understanding is that this will generate either:

- No words - because the entire expression is followed by *, which is 0
  or more occurrences.
- Words of this form: `aaab` `aaabaaab` `aaabaaabaaab`, i.e, the same expression repeated infinite times.

Please advise if my thinking on this is correct and help me understand this better if I'm off track.

Next, in general, for a given regular expression, how do I go about converting it to a CFG? Is there a formula or some kind of standard practice to do so? You may use the above regular expression or any expression for that matter as an example.

Thanks in advance!

Based on what has been discussed in the answer and comments to that answer, I assume the FA looks something like this:

[image: FA]

Comment: Is there a `space` before and after `+` ? And yes you should not ask two different questions in one post.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: All I am trying to do is get an understanding of how this works. You don't have to use the examples I've given - the important part for me is to understand the theory so that I can apply that understanding against anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression is a vast topic. Not everything can be explained in one post. I suggest you read about regex from [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info)

Here I will explain what your patterns will match in context of the `quantifiers` you used.

**Quantifiers:**

- `+` will match one or more patterns.
- `*` will match 0 or more.

**Regex:** `(aaa+b)*`

**Explanation:**

- Your first point is correct that it will match `nothing` as `*` quantifier is used.
- However your second point is incomplete.
  As you can see `+` is after `a`. It will be applied to only last `a` and it means one or more `a`.
  So following patterns will also be a match.
- `aaaab`: notice that there are first three `a` and then one `a` which matches the repetition caused by `+`
- `aaaaaabaab`: Here the first `aaaaaab` will be submatch of the whole match.

<kbd>**[You can better understand visually here.](https://regex101.com/r/wG7eQ5/1)**</kbd>

Comment: So at a bare minimum words will always start with 3 a's then finally 1 b. With one or more a's between the first 3 a's and the b?

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c: Exactly !

Comment: If I apply the star outside of that match, it means repeating that same pattern multiple times?

Comment: Could you show the regex ? It's unclear what you mean. Do you mean `(aaab)* ` ?

Comment: (aaa+b)* = (aaab)* = aaabaaabaab - basically repeating aaab infinitely many times. I understand that (aaa+b)* could also have been (aaaab)* = aaaabaaaab - basically repeating infinitely many times.

Comment: **(aaa+b)* ≠ (aaab)*** . `(aaa+b)*` is not repeating `aaab`. It's repeating `(aa then a(many times) then b)` infinitely. Just take care where you use `quantifiers`. It does makes a difference **where** you use them.

Comment: Please see the FA I've attached in the question and let me know if my thinking matches. I think we understand each other - i'm just not good in explaining it very well. I've created an FA that talks to this discussion - please let me know if it's accurate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106091/discussion-between-noob-and-c0d3l0g1c).